# spring boot: sending data to 1 endpoint but hiding from other

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple spring boot application, my model contains 3 fields. and controller exposes 2 endpoints /e1 and /e2. what I want to achieve is that when /e1 is called I want to return all 3 fields from my model by when /e2 is called I was to return just 2 fields and hiding the 3rd field from it.

is there a way to do it and how this can be done ? thanks

Comment: Can you at least show some snippet you are working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should always have 2 classes - entity and its dto presentation - even if they fields are very similar. This gives you:

- independcy from external consumers, you may change your model in future but the contract remains the same
- opportunity to use advantages of Hiberante laze loading
- easily solve your issue: just have 2 DTOs, one with all fields, other one without hidden field.

You might need [bean mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks) for converting entity to DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions you can try either of them ..

1. Create two POJO's One with 3 field and another with 2 fields and return accordingly.
2. If you dont want separate pojo then set value of all 3 fields in pojo and when /e2 called, iterate over it and explicitely blank out that value which you want hide.